# Can I use a Z-score with skewed and non-normal data?

Tags: normality-assumption, standardization, weibull-distribution

I've been working with some process cycle time data and scaling using the standard z-score in order to compare between parts of the full cycle time.

Should I use some other transformation since the data are heavily right-skewed/non-normal? ('outliers' can never take negative time and often take much longer than 'average')

Using the z-score still seems to "work" ...

```
###############
# R code    
###############
mydata <- rweibull(1000,1,1.5)
hist(mydata)
hist(scale(mydata))
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Of course, you can still calculate the $z$-score, but what are you trying to use it for? The number of standard deviations from the mean (which is what the $z$-score is) may not be a particularly useful statistic in some situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If X is highly skewed the Z statistic will not be normally distributed (or t if the standard deviation must be estimated. So the percentiles of Z will not be standard normal.  So in that sense it does not work.

Comment: To my understanding, X being highly skewed means the sample size was not big enough (central limit theorem). However I'm not sure, whether the population itself needs to be normal, in order for Z statistic to work. Does it?

Comment: The OP is talking about the population distribution and not the distribution of the mean. So sample size and the central limit theorem do not apply.

Answer (score 3):

The R code will work, but the z-score will be about as meaningful as the sentence "Grapes are phoning the fountain pen lightly."  It's a valid sentence, but doesn't convey anything meaningful.

Judging by your R code, it seems like you think your data is Weibull distributed.  In that case, I'd just use the Weibull statistic and not scale anything unless you absolutely have to.  Even though z-scores are taught in every intro statistics class, that doesn't mean you should use them all the time, and especially not if you don't have symmetric data.

Answer (score 1):

If the population is not normally distributed. In that case, the distribution of bar(X) {sample mean} approaches a normal distribution as as per central limit theorem; for large sample size. Though theoretically we say we are using Student's-t but for higher values of n (sample size or degree of freedom), t distribution & Z distribution are nearly equal.

Answer (score -4):

YOUR DATA DOESN'T HAVE TO BE NORMAL FOR A Z-TEST. (TOWNEND,2002) HOWEVER, THE VARIANCES SHOULD BE APPROXIMATELY EQUAL. TO  CHECK THAT CARRY OUT AN F-TEST ON YOUR TWO DATASETS, AND IF YOUR VARIANCES ARE APPROXIMATELY EQUAL, THE Z TEST RESULT IS USEFUL. IF NOT, TRANSFORM THE DATA.

Comment: The question is about transformation of a variable not a test, so I don't think your answer applies. Also, it is probably more informative if you give the full reference instead of just a name-year reference and some people object against SHOUTING.

Comment: I agree with @MaartenBuis but unlike him I will downvote this.